# Deserialization further address of json in c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I am deserializing a json in c#. but address field needs furher deserialization. help me how to do it

{"**Name**":"name something",
"**Start**":"2021-11-10T09:00:00",
"**End**":"2021-11-14T09:00:00",
"**AdditionalInformation**":"infoadfasf.",
"**Address**":{"Information":"Cancha Convive "Parque la Hermandad" colonia El Hogar, Tegucigalpa.","City":"Tegucigalpa, Francisco Moraz\u00e1n","CountryIso2":"HN"}}

i cant get the properties of address, eg address have (city, country..)

my c# code

```
public class Event
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalInformation { get; set; }
    public Address1 address1 { get; set; }
}

public class Address1
{
    public string Information { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string CountryIso2 { get; set; }
}
```

data service for deserialization

```
 public class DataService
{
   
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Event>?> GetEventsAsync()
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<Event>>(await File.ReadAllTextAsync("Data/Events.json"));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean further deserialization? But anyway you can deserialize it by create an `Address` model according to the JSON and declare the `Address` property as `Address` model type. And would be great to share your current code for the deserialization. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the classes you are using to deserialize, pls and code you have done so far?

Comment: i eddited please check again @Serge

Comment: i eddited please check again @YongShun

Comment: Show your `Address` class too. While I see you deserialize as `IEnumerable<Event>`, does your attached JSON is complete one or partial (one of the record) in JSON file?

Comment: @YongShun added the code json is complete one

Comment: 1. Modify the name for `address1` property in `Event` model to `Address`. 2. While you mentioned that the JSON is complete JSON in file, you should deserialize it as `Event` but not `IEnumerable<Event>`. `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Event>(await File.ReadAllTextAsync("Data/Events.json"));` The change of deserialize will import to the return type of `GetEventsAsync` method.

Comment: yes got it, thanks for the response you can write it in answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The `Address` field in the JSON is unmatched with the `address1` in `Event` model.

   1.1. Either rename the property to `Address`

```cs
public class Event
{
    ...

    public Address1 Address { get; set; }
}
```

1.2. Or using the `JsonProperty` attribute:

```cs
[JsonProperty("Address")]
public Address1 address1 { get; set; }
```

Would suggest using the approach *1.1* which is declaring the property with Pascal Casing naming, following the C# naming convention.

2. The provided JSON is an object, but not an array. You should deserialize as `Event` but not `IEnumerable<Event>`. Following change requires to change the method signature for `GetEventAsync` method as well.

```cs
public async Task<Event> GetEventAsync()
{
    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Event>(await File.ReadAllTextAsync("Data/Events.json"));
}
```